# Propel ORM add many to many relation data in single save

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, propel, relation

I have  a Post and  category model have a relation on many to many with category_post table

in real scenario i want to a add a post with  multiple  existing category id
 for Example

post have

```
   $postobj = new Post();
   $postobj->setTitle("First title");
   $postobj->setContent("First title");
```

and I have also existing category with  id

```
    $category_id = array(8,9,17,39)
```

I want to save post  with above category in a single save function like

```
  $postobj->save();
```

i can not figure out how we can  do this ?

Comment: i can do this with  CategoryPost class object  to save  data  over a loop

       CategoryPost>setPostId()
       CategoryPost>setCategoryId()
       CategoryPost->save()

But this is not a  good Way  , i want save data with all related data in  a single save function Like CakePhp

Comment: Hmm... I think Propel will do it in one DB hit if done a particular way. I think if you use `$postobj->addCategory($catobj);` (as many times as you need) and then do `$postobj->save();` it will do one hit. I'll see if I can confirm that in my test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after testing it looks like Propel WILL execute code like below in one transaction, but not one database hit. This is probably the most efficient way to do this with Propel, however:

```
$postobj = new Post();
$postobj->setTitle("First title");
$postobj->setContent("First title");

$category_id = array(8,9,17,39)
for ($i=0,$l=sizeof($category_id); $i<$l; ++$i) {
  $cp = new CategoryPost();
  $cp->setPost($postobj);
  $cp->setCategoryId($category_id[$i]);
  $postobj->addCategoryPost($cp);
}
$postobj->save(); // this will save the Post AND the CategoryPost objects
```

**UPDATE**
If you wanted to put this code into a helper function that allowed you to pass in some data and save it, then you could do this (**WARNING: this is untested, be careful**):

```
class Post extends BasePost
{
  public function saveAllData($data, PropelPDO $con = null) {
    // might want to do some audits on input..
    $this->fromArray($data); // catches most data

    // add relationships
    if (isset($data['categoryIds']) && is_array($data['categoryIds'])) {
      for ($i=0,$l=sizeof($data['categoryIds']); $i<$l; ++$i) {
        $cp = new CategoryPost();
        $cp->setPost($this);
        $cp->setCategoryId($data['categoryIds'][$i]);
        $this->addCategoryPost($cp);
      }
    }

    // do the save
    // NOTE: you might want to do validations first, etc
    return $this->save($con);
  }
}
```

Then you would call it from your script like so:

```
...
$data = array(
  "ColumnName"=>"value", // NOTE: the ColumnName must match the Propel column
  ...
  "CategoryIds"=>array(2,3,4,5)
);
$post = new Post();
$post->saveAllData($data); // careful, this could throw Exceptions
```

Comment: Thanks @jakerella but can we save in more other sort way like cake this will not happen in real in propel for ex 
$postobj->addCategory($category_id);
$postobj->save();
but can we do  this is other sort way?

iterate over category_id and call CategoryPost object and save related records is not smart way i think . but this is one of best solution .

Comment: I'm not sure what other way you would like to do it. Can you link to an example from cake for comparison?

Comment: Cake save all related data in single save function  like this
$data = array('Post' => array("colunm name" => 'value'..),
 'Category' => array('Category' => array(2,3,4,5)));
$postobj->saveAll($data );
this Will save record  in post table a  as well as join table categorypost also.

Comment: I'd have to look at the cake source code, but my guess is that it is hitting the database just as much as Propel. While Peopel's code may seem more verbose, it is much more organized and object-oriented (IMO). You could write a helper function in your `Post` class to have a similar syntax if you want though.

Comment: Thanks again 
but how we can make  helper function in post Class Any clue?
Thanks Again.